# android multi user separation for external storage

Tags: android, storage, external, multi-user

I have some doubt on android multi user separation of external storage

Say the owner installs com.example.test package, which has the following code

```
File[] path = getExternalFilesDirs(null);
Log.d("getExternalFilesDirs",path.toString());
```

The log for owner is

```
/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.test/files
```

Now since the same app is already installed, I run the same app on different
user.

The log for the above code for different user is

```
/storage/sdcard/Android/data/com.example.test/files
```

My confusion is same location shared by owner and other users, I expected the
location to be private to users.

I expected somthing like this for external storage for multiple users

/storage/sdcard/Android/data/user/0/com.example.test/files
/storage/sdcard/Android/data/user/13/com.example.test/files

How Multi-user separation is done for external storage?
Whereas the following code for internal storage when run under different users shows

```
            path=getFilesDir();
            Log.d("getFilesDir",path.toString());


/data/user/10/com.example.test/files  --> for user1
/data/user/11/com.example.test/files  --> for user2
/data/user/13/com.example.test/files  --> for user3
```

Here I can see the multi user separation in internal storage.
All the experiments were done on AVD for Nexus 4 by Google , Target Name Android 5.0 , API Level 21.

Comment: check this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/23203257/1061944, it answers your question